# How do I convert from an *ecdsa.PublicKey to crypto/ecdh *ecdh.PublicKey?

Tags: go, cryptography, ecdsa, ecdh

This is my old code.

```
    PKCS8GCSprvkey, _ := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey([]byte(privateKeyFile))
    GCSprvkey, _ := PKCS8GCSprvkey.(*ecdsa.PrivateKey)
 

    GCSpubkey, _ := os.ReadFile("public_key.txt")
    Clientkeybuffer := ciphertext[0:len(GCSpubkey)]
    parseClientpub, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(Clientkeybuffer)
    Clientpubkey, _ := parseClientpub.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
 
    GCSsecret, _ := GCSprvkey.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarMult(Clientpubkey.X, Clientpubkey.Y, GCSprvkey.D.Bytes())
    GCSsecretstring := GCSsecret.Text(16)
```

But the method

```
GCSprvkey.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarMult(Clientpubkey.X, Clientpubkey.Y, GCSprvkey.D.Bytes())
```

.ScalarMult() is deprecated and it says "this is a low-Level unsafe API. For ECDH, use the crypto/ecdh package. Most of uses of ScalarMult can be replaced by a call to the ECDH methods of NIST curves in crypto/ECDH." .  I'm not sure how to use the `crypto/ecdh` of golang to achieve the same thing. I tried to load my public key file into an *ecdh.PublicKey but I keep getting `invalid public key` error.

I've tried to convert the ecdsa.PublicKey to ecdh.PublicKey but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that in the `ecdsa` package, there are methods which convert each key type to their counterparts in the the `ecdh` package. This extra conversion step is mentioned in the `ecdh` documentation.

From [`ecdh.PrivateKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdh#PrivateKey):

> For NIST curves, they then need to be converted with [`ecdsa.PrivateKey.ECDH`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdsa#PrivateKey.ECDH) after parsing.

From [`ecdh.PublicKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdh#PublicKey):

> For NIST curves, they then need to be converted with [`ecdsa.PublicKey.ECDH`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/ecdsa#PublicKey.ECDH) after parsing.

---

Taking your code example, here's how you'd parse the keys using `x509`, convert them to `ecdh` keys, and then compute a shared secret.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    k1PrivateDER, k2PublicDER := mustGenerateKeyPair()

    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(k1PrivateDER)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse private key: %v", err)
    }
    ecdsaPrivateKey, ok := privateKey.(*ecdsa.PrivateKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("Private key is not an ECDSA key.")
    }
    ecdhPrivateKey, err := ecdsaPrivateKey.ECDH()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to convert to ECDH key: %v", err)
    }

    publicKey, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(k2PublicDER)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse public key: %v", err)
    }
    ecdsaPublicKey, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatalf("Public key is not an ECDSA key.")
    }
    ecdhPublicKey, err := ecdsaPublicKey.ECDH()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to convert to ECDH key: %v", err)
    }

    secret, err := ecdhPrivateKey.ECDH(ecdhPublicKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to compute ECDH shared secret: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("secret = %x\n", secret)
}

func mustGenerateKeyPair() (k1PrivateDER, k2PublicDER []byte) {
    k1, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    k1PrivateDER, err = x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(k1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    k2, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(elliptic.P256(), rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    k2PublicDER, err = x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(k2.Public())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return k1PrivateDER, k2PublicDER
}
```

Output:

```
secret = 4c1858f80818886fd2978d4c1198aa59aa70865702367bfe8326bb20c4837424
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5rodUbvFX6E)